# Compile mustache java template directly to JSON with a JSON string writer instead of a StringWriter

Tags: java, json, gson, mustache

I'd like to compile a mustache Java template directly to JSON with a Writer that writes an escape JSON string instead of using a `StringWriter` and then executing `toString()`.

Here is my current code -

```
MustacheFactory mustacheFactory = new DefaultMustacheFactory();

// reader is my InputStreamReader pointing to my template file
Mustache mustache = mustacheFactory.compile(reader, "example");

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
mustache.execute(stringWriter, view);
String html = stringWriter.toString();

// elementAdapter is a TypeAdapter<JsonElement>
elementAdapter.write(out, new JsonPrimitive(html));
```

This is a bit confusing, let me know if you have specific questions.  But, basically, I'm looking for an API which can do the following -

```
MustacheFactory mustacheFactory = new DefaultMustacheFactory();

// reader is my InputStreamReader pointing to my template file
Mustache mustache = mustacheFactory.compile(reader, "example");

JsonStringWriter writer = new JsonStringWriter(response.getWriter());
mustache.execute(writer, view);
```

The pseudo implementation of JsonStringWriter would be -

```
public class JsonStringWriter extends Writer
{
  Writer writer;

  public JsonStringValueWriter(PrintWriter writer)
  {
    this.writer = writer;
  }

  @Override
  public void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)
  {
    // check cbuf for string escape characters
    // if found, write escape to underlying writer
    // otherwise, write cbuf to underlying writer
  }
}
```

I don't want to write this class.  My question is what JSON API currently has this class and can you provide a reference to it?  Thanks.